# Using circuitikz, how do I make a ground node and link to it from several others?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'd like to get two or three nodes linking to a ground symbol (this is not an electric circuit), as in this attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[](a){X};
\node[](b)[right=of a]{Y};
\node[ground](g)[below=of a]{};
\draw[-] (a.south) -- (g.north);
\draw[-] (b.south) -- (g.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `north' (in 'north').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 \node[ground](g)[below=of a.east]{};

?
```

And yet, TeX still outputs the PDF, which seems correct... What am I doing wrong?

(I am willing to use another library instead of circuitikz if it makes things easier)

**edit:** included an example with two nodes linking to ground, not only one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The monopole `ground` has only `center` anchor. So you can not refer to its `north`. Also `positioning` library uses that anchor when you say *put it `below` such and such*, so we have to reanchor it to its center. Hence everytime you want to refer to it either should use the node name or `node name.center` syntax. I would go with the TikZ' own circuit library to avoid such unforeseen problems.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a){X};
\node (b)[right=of a]{Y};
\node[ground,below=of a,anchor=center] (g) {};
\draw (a.south) -- (g);
\draw (b.south) -- (g);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]